# How do I find all the frequencies for my local TRACON?

Tags: usa, faa, approach, frequency, tracon

I'd like to program my hand held radio with all frequencies that I can expect to need around my area.  Specifically, **I'd like to find an official list of all the frequencies used by the local Tracon facility.**

Looking in the Chart Supplement for the primary airport, I get a list of frequencies for approach and departure at that airport.

If I look at charts for airports around the periphery, I can find other frequencies not listed in the supplement for the primary airport.

My example is Salt Lake City.  Outlying airport is Provo Municipal from which you can reach Salt Lake Approach on 118.85.  I'd guess terrain prevents collocation of the 118.85 antenna with the others.

I'd also be interested to know if there are maps available for ATC sectors within facilities.

Comment: http://www.radioreference.com/apps/db/?aid=2958

Comment: I visited that site while wanting to program my radio.  Very valuable, however, it misses the example frequency of 118.85

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Emphasis added to the heart of the question.  I could also add "Do you know if this list exists and where to find it?"

Answer (score 6):

There are sector maps available, and each facility updates them periodically.  They are published.  My understanding is that sectors are joined and separated frequently, even based on the minute to minute workload.
(I have a set of charts showing High, Low Center and tracon sectors. I haven't found a public source for those charts yet.  Here is a set of maps, but I would like to provide direct FAA maps.  https://ivaous.org/academy/index.php/controllers/procedures-and-organization  )

The chart supplement and AFD are good places for common frequencies, however most facilities have additional frequencies.  They might be used for certain events, emergencies, when VIPs are being handled, during extreme congestion and when there are problems with the primary frequencies.  I do not know of a good source for those backup frequencies, which is published.

There are radio reference listings of ATC frequencies, however, they are not always accurate.  While the may show the station frequency assignments, they may not show the true facility usage.

As an example, here is a compilation of Boston Air Route Traffic Control Sectors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Air_Route_Traffic_Control_Center#Low_Altitude_Sectors_2

Addendum:  FAA Facility Transmitting Authorization (FTA) would be the document, prepared for each facility, which would list all the frequencies that facility is authorized to use.  The genesis and use of the FTA is covered in this FAA Order: https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/order/6050_32b_with_chg_1_and_2_incorporated.pdf

> For FAA-owned systems, this number will be the Facility Transmitting
>   Author ization (FTA) number assigned by FAA Spectrum Engineering. For
>   non-federally-owned systems, this number will be the Federal
>   Communications Commission (FCC) license number or “call sign” assigned
>   by the FCC.  For military-owned systems, this number will be the
>   National Telecommunications and Information Administration (NTIA)
>   serial number assigned by the FTIA.

So if you are trying to obtain frequencies for a military base, which may be working with local FAA facilities, you will also need to get the NTIA/FTIA data.

The FTA is public information, but I am unaware of an Order or publically accessible database for the FTA.  When I see an avionics inspector later today, I will ask her if she knows where FTAs can be looked up.

Answer (score 2):

The "ATC Tower and Satellite Airport Communications (TWR)" file is available at the FAA's website under the [28-Day NASR Subscription](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/aero_data/NASR_Subscription/):

https://nfdc.faa.gov/webContent/28DaySub/2022-03-24/TWR.zip

If you search this file for `S56` (the identifier for Salt Lake City TRACON), you will find the following entries:

```
TWR7S56 118.85  APCH/P DEP/P  25269.*A  PVU ANMUTAH  UTPROVO  PROVO MUNI  40-13-09.000N 144789.000N111-43-24.100W402204.100WCDC CEDAR CITY  ANMUTAH  UTSALT LAKE CITY
TWR7S56 118.85  APCH/P DEP/P  25300.1*A  SPK ANMUTAH  UTSPANISH FORK  SPANISH FORK MUNI/WOODHOUSE FLD  40-08-42.100N 144522.100N111-40-03.700W402003.700WCDC CEDAR CITY  ANMUTAH  UTSALT LAKE CITY
```

(The entries list very detailed coordinates which unfortunately refer to the locations of the mentioned *airports* rather than the location of the actual radio antennas.)

The inclusion of 118.85 indicates that the rest of the entries for S56 are indeed exhaustive:

```
TWR1S56 03/24/2022           ANMUTAH                          UTSALT LAKE CITY   
TWR2S56                                                                          
TWR3S56 120.2                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR5S56 RADAR             RADAR                                                  
TWR7S56 118.85                                      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 118.85                                      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 120.7                                       CD/P                         
TWR7S56 120.9                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 120.9                                       VFR CD/P                     
TWR7S56 120.9 ;SOUTH OF 41 DEG LAT                  CLASS B                      
TWR7S56 120.9 ;SOUTH OF 41 DEG LAT BLW 8000 FT      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 121.1                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 121.1                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 121.1                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 121.1                                       BASIC RADAR                  
TWR7S56 121.1 ;NORTH OF 41 DEG LAT                  CLASS B                      
TWR7S56 121.1 ;NORTH OF 41 DEG LAT BLW 8000 FT      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 124.1                                       CD/P                         
TWR7S56 124.4                                       CD/P                         
TWR7S56 124.4                                       IFR CD/P                     
TWR7S56 124.9                                       BEARR STAR                   
TWR7S56 124.9                                       BRIGHAM CITY STAR            
TWR7S56 124.9                                       NORDK RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 124.9                                       SKEES RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 124.9 ;300-340 ABV 8000 FT                  APCH/P                       
TWR7S56 125.7                                       APCH/P DEP/P IC              
TWR7S56 125.7                                       FINAL                        
TWR7S56 126.0                                       CD/P                         
TWR7S56 126.25                                      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 126.25                                      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 126.25                                      CGULL DP                     
TWR7S56 126.25                                      DZERT DP                     
TWR7S56 126.25 ;250-300 ABV 8000 FT                 DEP/P                        
TWR7S56 127.0                                       CD/P                         
TWR7S56 128.1                                       ARCHZ DP                     
TWR7S56 128.1                                       DELTA RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 128.1                                       JAMMN STAR                   
TWR7S56 128.1                                       SEVYR DP                     
TWR7S56 128.1                                       WAATS RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 128.1 ;160-250 ABV 8000 FT                  APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 128.6                                       BONNEVILLE STAR              
TWR7S56 128.6                                       FAIRFIELD DP                 
TWR7S56 128.6                                       LEEHY RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 128.6                                       QWENN RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 128.6                                       SALT LAKE DP                 
TWR7S56 128.6                                       SPANE STAR                   
TWR7S56 128.6                                       ZIONZ RNAV DP                
TWR7S56 128.6 ;110-160 TCH ABV 8,000 FT             APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 135.5                                       APCH/P DEP/P IC              
TWR7S56 135.5                                       RUGGD DP                     
TWR7S56 135.5 ;340-110 ABV 8000 FT.                 APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 233.7                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 233.7                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 233.7                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 257.2                                       APCH/P                       
TWR7S56 257.2 ;SOUTH OF 41 DEG LAT                  CLASS B                      
TWR7S56 269.625                                     APCH/P                       
TWR7S56 284.6                                       APCH/P DEP/P IC              
TWR7S56 284.6                                       FINAL                        
TWR7S56 290.3                                       BEARR STAR                   
TWR7S56 290.3                                       BRIGHAM CITY  STAR            
TWR7S56 290.3                                       NORDK RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 290.3                                       SKEES RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 290.3 ;300-340 TCH ABV 8000 FT              APCH/P                       
TWR7S56 307.05                                      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 307.05                                      ARCHZ DP                     
TWR7S56 307.05                                      DELTA RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 307.05                                      JAMMN STAR                   
TWR7S56 307.05                                      SEVYR STAR                   
TWR7S56 307.05                                      WAATS RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 316.15                                      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 316.15                                      DEP/P                        
TWR7S56 316.15                                      RUGGD DP                     
TWR7S56 319.25                                      APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 319.25 ;NORTH OF 41 DEG LAT                 CLASS B                      
TWR7S56 319.25 ;NORTH OF 41 DEG LAT                 CLASS B                      
TWR7S56 319.25 ;NORTH OF 41 DEG LAT                 CLASS B                      
TWR7S56 319.25 ;NORTH OF 41 DEG LAT                 CLASS B                      
TWR7S56 322.3                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 322.3                                       FAIRFIELD DP                 
TWR7S56 322.3                                       LEEHY RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 322.3                                       QWENN RNAV STAR              
TWR7S56 322.3                                       SALT LAKE DP                 
TWR7S56 322.3                                       SPANE STAR                   
TWR7S56 322.3                                       ZIONZ DP                     
TWR7S56 322.3 ;110-160 TCH ABV 8000 FT              APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 335.8                                       CD/P                         
TWR7S56 353.6                                       APCH/P DEP/P                 
TWR7S56 353.825                                     CGULL DP                     
TWR7S56 353.825                                     DZERT DP                     
TWR7S56 353.825 ;250-300 ABV 8000 FT                APCH/P DEP/P
```

Comment: However you should take that "exhaustive" comment with a grain of salt, because I just looked up my own facility and there is one VHF/UHF pair that is **not** listed. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

These might help.

https://www.natca.org/index.php/insider-articles/630-facility-spotlight-salt-lake-tracon

https://www.radioreference.com/apps/db/?aid=2237

I use radioreference.com to find ATIS and Tower frequencies at KSFO my home airport.

Hope this helps, 
Charlie :)

Comment: Please include here the relevant parts of those pages. The pages might disappear and your answer would not be useful anymore.